# How create node using gqlalchemy in neo4j?

Tags: python, memgraphdb

I tried to create node and relationship using gqlalchemy in neo4j as per the memgraph documentation but it did not worked

```
from gqlalchemy import Memgraph, Node, Relationship, Field,Neo4j
from typing import Optional

db = Neo4j(host="localhost", port="7687", username="neo4j", password="12345678")


class User(Node):
    id: str = Field(index=True, exist=True, unique=True, db=db)
    username: str = Field(index=True, exist=True, unique=True, db=db)

class Language(Node):
    name: str = Field(unique=True, db=db)

user = User(id="3", username="John")
db.save_node(user)

language = Language(name="en")
db.save_node(user)
```

Got an error as

```
raise Neo4jError.hydrate(**metadata)
neo4j.exceptions.ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Schema.IndexAlreadyExists} {message: There already exists an index (:User {id}). A constraint cannot be created until the index has been dropped.}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first look, it looks like you are trying to create two **identical nodes** while having a unique constraint on node id:

```
user = User(id="3", username="John")
db.save_node(user)

language = Language(name="en")
db.save_node(user)
```

I would start with that.

**On error message:**

Neo4j changed how they handle indexes in version 5.x. Not 100% sure about the compatibility of GQLalchemy with version 5.x and above. But from the error message, I would say that GQLalchemy is trying to recreate the index that already exists. This yields an error from the Neo4j side. Take a look at Neo4j 5.x docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can try using a cypher to handle indexes with Neo4j and GQLAlchemy. Memgraph is a more compatible with GQLAlchemy since it is made primarily for Memgraph. Consider moving to Memgraph if GQLalchemy is a hard requirement.